# react-native android Could not retrieve file for contentUri http://192.168.108.18:8180/app/upload/storag/app_head/201610131627080535.jpg

Tags: android

[enter image description here][1]
   When I used react-native fetch formData upload a image , in iOS it worked,but in android it console.log 'Could not retrieve file for contentUri http://192.168.108.18:8180/app/upload/storag/app_head/201610131627080535.jpg'.
Could someone please let me know how can I solve it?

It is my code:

var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('owner_id',this.state.owner_id)
        formData.append('head_portraits',{uri:this.state.head_portraits,type:'image/jpeg'||'image/png',name:'headImage.jpg'});
        formData.append('owner_name',this.state.owner_name)
        formData.append('sex',this.state.sex)
        formData.append('mobile',this.state.mobile)
        fetch('http://192.168.108.18:8180/app/app/owner/guest/addOwner?', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    },
            body:formData
                }).then((response) => response.json()
                ).then((responseJson) => {
                        console.log(responseJson);
                        if (responseJson.status === '0000'){
                            Alert.alert('提示','保存个人信息成功!',[
                                {
                                    text: '确定'
                                }
                            ])
                        }
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log('错误:' + error);
                    })
        }

Comment: How do I ask a good question? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

```
formData.append('head_portraits', { 
    uri: this.state.head_portraits,
    type:'image/jpeg'||'image/png',
    name:'headImage.jpg'
});
```

to

```
formData.append('head_portraits',{
    uri:'file://' + this.state.head_portraits,
    type:'image/jpeg'||'image/png',
    name:'headImage.jpg'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this `file://` before the `this.state.head_portraits` for Android. In iOS, it works without `file://`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).